# How can I repeatedly call a method while button is pressed down (Java with Swing)?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, mousepress

I am trying to call a method repeatedly for as long as a button is pressed. But I get an infinite loop. Could anyone help me?

```
private void jButton6MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {  
    pressed = true;
    while(pressed) {
        car.accelerator();
    }
}

private void jButton6MouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
   pressed = false;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You get an infinite loop because you have written an infinite loop, you need

```
JButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   car.accelerator();
  }
});
```

If you want it to repeat the action while it's held own this is more difficult, [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Java/Q_20409837.html) is an example of how you do that. In short you need to use threads.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that once pressed is set to true, you never exit the while loop, so the fact that the button isn't being pressed never registers, the program is stuck.  The only thing I can think of is using a timer to check periodically the state of the JButton.  Alternatively, you can use multi-threading.  That is, have PRESSED be a field in thread 1 that is set by the JButton (as you've done), and have the loop in a thread 2, checking on the status of PRESSED in thread 1.

Edit: Whoops, I see that bmorris591 has already suggested multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

Swing thread enters an infinite loop.
You should run your loop in another thread:

```
private class BooleanHolder{
   bool pressed;
};
final BooleanHolder pressed = new BooleanHolder();


private void jButton6MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {  
   presed.pressed=true;
   Thread t = new Thread( new Runnable(){
      public void run(){
         while(pressed.pressed)
         {
           car.accelerator();
         }
      }
   }
   t.start();
}
private void jButton6MouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
   pressed.pressed=false;
}
```

Comment: Using raw `Threads` is not really recommended - `ExecutorService` and other things in `java.util.concurrent` are better.

Comment: You are right. The aime of thé code snipet is just to illustrate the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what `car.accelerator();` does, it's impossible to make a accurate suggestion.

If `car.accelerator()` is interacting with the UI in any way, you need to be careful, you should never update the UI from any Thread other then the EDT.

Instead, you could use a rapid firing `javax.swing.Timer`

```
private Timer accelerateTimer;

//** ... **//

accelerateTimer = new Timer(15, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed() {
        car.accelerator();
    }
});
accelerateTimer.setRepeats(true);

//** ... **//

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
    accelerateTimer.restart();
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
    accelerateTimer.stop()
}
```